# jQuery ui slider - ui slider handle out of div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Please help me with my problem...
How and where to set that when reaching 100% on the right **.ui-slider-handle** does not exceed the div

```
Live preview https://codepen.io/Melwee/pen/Exjwoyo
```

**And here is a picture to clarify what I mean**
[image]

Comment: Answer edited. Please see my alternative approach using color of the left and right borders

Answer (score 0):

Well. I don't know if you'll accept this as an answer but actually your question doesn't have a proper one. One can only give you some different point of view on this matter.

I think if you add some `margin-left` to `.ui-slider-handle` like:

```
margin-left: -25px;
```

And then extend `.lc-slider` 's `padding` like:

```
padding: 5px 20px;
```

it'll look better.

https://codepen.io/batuhabibi/pen/MWwEQKX

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still doesn't solve my problem it still goes through the div.... And sorry but I did not understand your comment ...
I'm from Slovakia ... and I don't know English very well ... Google Translator also helped me with the translation

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the left margin as the half of the disc size, like for the `border-radius`. After that, set the left and right borders of the slider to the same color of the widget:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border: 14px solid #f9f9ff;
  height: 53px;
  width: 53px;
  border-radius: 27px;
  background: #ff4c60;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-left: -27px; /* set margin to 0.5 the width */
}

.ui-slider.ui-slider-horizontal {
  border-left: 25px solid #ff4c60 !important;
  border-right: 24px solid #ffffff !important;
}
.ui-slider.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

After that, You just only need to adjust the footer:

```
.lc-slider-footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 4px; /* adjust footer */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```